# Email Message and File Sending via LAN Microsoft Outlook

Tags: outlook

Good Afternoon to everyone I want to ask something because this is the first time i encounter this

Possible Techniques that my friend tells me

1. Send a message and file from PC1 to PC2 via Lan (utp cable and no
   internet)
2. PC1 will act as client(sender) PC2 will act as server(database)

   Ex: Joe will send a file to Mary and he will use
   PC1 is it possible that the message and file will save in PC2? and if Mary will
   login to PC1 he will get the message.

I dont know what to do but my goal here is that how to send a message and file using LAN no net? Do my techniques is correct? any help or tuts willbe a great help TY

Note: Outlook in Win7

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. … every question about programming.  Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on http://superuser.com/tour.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can write and then send an email to Mary using Outlook. Also you can develop a VBA macro or an add-in to save the message and attached files to the DB. If that is what you are looking for, I'd suggest starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article in MSDN.